# Issue using WebdriverIO to test Tauri app

Tags: rust, webdriver-io, tauri

I am using the https://github.com/chippers/hello_tauri example application from the Tauri documentation.

The app builds and runs correctly.

Had to change the port in `wdio.conf.js` to `4445` but nothing else was modified.

When running the `webdriverio` tests I get a blank Edge window opening with `data:,` in the address bar.

Using Windows 11, EdgeDriver version: 110.0.1587.46, Tauri-Driver version: 0.1.2

Error message, makes sense as the window is blank:

```
[0-0] 2023-02-16T11:11:53.245Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND findElement("css selector", "body > h1")
[0-0] 2023-02-16T11:11:53.245Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:4445/session/661c211404b1904cb56f6d928fde54a1/element     
[0-0] 2023-02-16T11:11:53.245Z INFO webdriver: DATA { using: 'css selector', value: 'body > h1' }
[0-0] 2023-02-16T11:11:53.261Z INFO webdriver: RESULT {
[0-0]   error: 'no such element',
[0-0]   message: 'no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"body > h1"}\n' +
[0-0]     '  (Session info: MicrosoftEdge=110.0.1587.46)',
[0-0]   stacktrace: 'Backtrace:\n' +
[0-0]     '\tMicrosoft::Applications::Events::EventProperties::SetProperty [0x00007FF745074902+14722]\n' +
[0-0]     '\tMicrosoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::EventProperty [0x00007FF74500B992+817442]\n' +
[0-0]     '\t(No symbol) [0x00007FF744C9DB50]\n' +
[0-0]     '\t(No symbol) [0x00007FF744CE0585]\n' +
[0-0]     '\t(No symbol) [0x00007FF744CE070C]\n' +
[0-0]     '\t(No symbol) [0x00007FF744D1C277]\n' +
[0-0]     '\t(No symbol) [0x00007FF744D006CF]\n' +
[0-0]     '\t(No symbol) [0x00007FF744CD3121]\n' +
[0-0]     '\t(No symbol) [0x00007FF744D196FE]\n' +
[0-0]     '\t(No symbol) [0x00007FF744D00343]\n' +
[0-0]     '\t(No symbol) [0x00007FF744CD1FFC]\n' +
[0-0]     '\t(No symbol) [0x00007FF744CD0F7E]\n' +
[0-0]     '\t(No symbol) [0x00007FF744CD27EE]\n' +
[0-0]     '\tMicrosoft::Applications::Events::EventProperties::SetProperty [0x00007FF744EEF580+181072]\n' +
[0-0]     '\t(No symbol) [0x00007FF744DA07F7]\n' +
[0-0]     '\tMicrosoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::EventProperty [0x00007FF744F50252+49634]\n' +
[0-0]     '\tMicrosoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::EventProperty [0x00007FF744F53455+62437]\n' +
[0-0]     '\tMicrosoft::Applications::Events::ILogManager::DispatchEventBroadcast [0x00007FF745262038+1407928]\n' +
[0-0]     '\tMicrosoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::EventProperty [0x00007FF745013E9F+851503]\n' +
[0-0]     '\tMicrosoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::EventProperty [0x00007FF745018F04+872084]\n' +
[0-0]     '\tMicrosoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::EventProperty [0x00007FF74501905C+872428]\n' +
[0-0]     '\tMicrosoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::EventProperty [0x00007FF74502136B+905979]\n' +
[0-0]     '\tBaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFE8E3026BD+29]\n' +
[0-0]     '\tRtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFE8ED6DFB8+40]\n'
[0-0] }
```

Am I doing something wrong, were there breaking changes in newer version of the Edge/Tauri webdrivers? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue set `hostname` to `127.0.0.1` and add `.exe` to the binary path.